# Идентификация элемента

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

На странице выводятся данные из таблицы MySQL:

---

1. Имя: Дмитрий. Возраст: 24. [редактировать]
2. Имя: Алексей. Возраст: 31. [редактировать]
3. Имя: Николай. Возраст: 29. [редактировать]

---

[редактировать] - это ссылка, которая ведет на другую страницу, где вместо имени и возраста появляются формы, в которых можно изменить информацию. После нажатия на кнопку информация в таблице MySQL меняется:
`"UPDATE providers SET name = '$name' WHERE` **id = 2** `"`
Как идентифицировать элемент, который выбрал пользователь? Например, если он нажал на второй пункт, то есть *2. Имя: Алексей. Возраст: 31. [редактировать]*, то должна редактироваться информация именно об Алексее.

Comment: Очевидно, что по ID. Сделайте hidden поле с ним.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в URL'e передаёте id элемента, который планируется отредактировать: `/user/edit?id=1`

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $userId = (int) $_GET['id']; 
} else {
    throw new Exception('Id пользователя не задан');
}
```

и дальше по id выбираете нужные данные из БД, и формируете форму.

Comment: спасибо, всё работает)